# Cancel joining the site for newsletter subscription does nothing

Tags: bug, newsletter, subscription

You can manage newsletter subscription on the [SE newsletter page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters). However to subscribe for a specific site you need to be a member on it, if not, than clicking on subsribe link:

> [image: subsribe]

will refers you to account confirmation page:

> [image: confirm]

Clicking on cancel here does nothing (actually just refreshes the current page). My expectation was that cancel should redirect you back to newsletter catalog.